Why is it that all the numeric values are displayed as 0?
I am writing my first ASP.NET Blazor application. I'm trying to display data from a table in a database. Here's the definition of the table:
public partial class Entry
{
    [Key, Column("Video Number", Order = 0)]
    public short VideoNumber { get; set; }
    [Key, Column("Entry", Order = 1)]
    public byte Entry1 { get; set; }
    public short ShowCode { get; set; }
    public string EpisodeName { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime? ActualPlayTime { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? ActualPlayTime1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Show Show { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Video VideoNumberNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}

And here's a code snippet of the Blazor code where I'm trying to display the data in an HTML table:
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Video Number</th>
            <th>Episode Name</th>
            <th>Entry1</th>
            <th>Show Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@entry.VideoNumber</td>
                <td>@entry.EpisodeName</td>
                <td>@entry.Entry1</td>
                <td>@entry.ShowCode</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

All VideoNumbers are displayed as 0. However, the EpisodeName is fine. Moreover, using Swagger, all the VideoNumbers are displayed properly. I tried searching for what might be causing the numeric values (VideoNumber and ShowCode to be displayed as 0) and came across this post from here on Stack Overflow Entity Framework Code First - Cast smallint and integer to int32. However, this wasn't helpful, as I tried putting in the HasColumnType("SMALLINT") but it didn't make a difference.
So, why doesn't it display the correct value in the Blazor/HTML code, but Swagger does display the correct value?
Addendum
This is how I read the Entries in the minimal API:
private async Task<Entry[]?> LoadEntriesFromApi(string uri, HttpClient httpClient) 
{
    using var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    try
    {
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws if not 200-299
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.ReasonPhrase);
        return Array.Empty<Entry>();
    }

    if (httpResponse is object && httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType != null && httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
    {
        try
        {
            var contentStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); 
            var bozo = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Entry[]>(contentStream, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
            return bozo;
        }
        catch (JsonException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HTTP Response was invalid and cannot be deserialized. Exception type {ex.GetType().ToString()}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP Response was invalid and cannot be deserialized.");
    }
    return Array.Empty<Entry>();
}

BTW, I am starting small. This is the only endpoint I have in the API at this point.

The problem isn't in the code you have posted. Try setting up a [mre]. Start small, w/o EF.

You mention Swagger, so apparently you use an API to get data to your client-side Blazor app. And the API returns the data correctly. So how do you read that data, as the problem seems to be there? Compare the JSON from the API with the class you deserialize into

@HansKeﬆing might not be a client side app(it's tagged as SS; nothing prohibiting a BSS app from calling an API) - not that this alters your very wise point about checking the deser

If you change the code to add =1 after the VideoNumber property, do they all start showing as 1? It would appear to confirm Hans' point. Show us the code that interprets the response from the API you call. It could be as simple as the API is outputting "VideoNumer" ie a typo in its json

We need the example for how this blazor page show the VideoNumber. Then we could know what has happened.

@BrandoZhang I thought the second code snippet would have been sufficient. However, I am willing to provide more. Do you want the whole page?

How you get that entries inside the blazor page? Are you make sure the entries contains all contains the right value ?

It could be a JSon issue but there's  a total lack of information about that.

I've just added the code I've written in the API to get the data

There still isn't anything here to go on. Really start by creating a [mre].  Just a few lines to show that Blazor does handle numerics.  Do you know how to use a debugger?

Yes, Hank, I know how to use a debugger. I have been using debuggers for many years in many different IDEs.

Not really an answer but a mre in order to refute the question in the title:
<div>
    <p>@x</p>
    <p>@y</p>
    <p>@z</p>
</div>

@code {
    int x = 1;
    short y = 2;
    byte z = 3;
}

Extend this to match your situation, in steps.

Thank you for suggesting this. I've discovered what was the problem. In the Blazor page I had this entries = await LoadEntriesFromApi("https://localhost:7057/show1", Http);, which is WRONG!!! It should have been entries = await LoadEntriesFromApi("https://localhost:7057/entries", Http);. Show1 is another class, which I haven't implemented yet. Sometimes I get hyper focused upon minute details, that I miss the obvious.  ARGH!!!!!!!!!!! I've been working on this for weeks and missed the obvious. Thank you again, Henk.
